# How to apply already running jQuery scripts to content called by Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh

I'm dealing with this problem. I run some jQuery scripts on my page and it works fine. The problem comes, when I want to apply those scripts to a content, that is called by AJAX.

I created a code sample, that demonstrates the problem.
It consists of 3 files - **index.html, target.html and main.js**

**Index.html (just the `<body>`)**

```
<body>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='main.js'></script>  

    <div id='main'>

        <button>Call Ajax</button>
        <br /><br />
        <a href='index.html?clicked=1'>Some link</a>

    </div>

    <div id='target'></div>

</body>
```

**Target.html**

```
<a href='index.html?clicked=1'>Some link 2</a>
```

**Main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a').live("click", function() {
        if(!confirm('Are you sure?'))
            return false
    });

    $('button').click(function() {
        $.post('target.html', function(data) {
            $('#target').html(data);
        });
    }); 

});
```

So let's say, I want the user to confirm every time he clicked on `<a>` tag. I click on the  tag inside of #main `<div>` and it works fine. I click the "Call ajax" button, a link appears, I click it and no confirm shows up.

So, I thought I'd put `<script type='text/javascript' src='main.js'></script>` inside of the **target.html** file.

This works fine, to the point when I click the first link (inside #main div) again. Than the confirm shows up 2 times, instead of just one.

I found on the web, that some people deal with this using `.live()` method, or `$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){`, but I couldn't get it running.

Can anyone provide a working solution? Thanks, Mike.

Answer (score 1):

couldnt get it running is a bad excuse. you certainly can get it running, and should, since this is the right way to do this.

try this:

```
var confirmFn = function() {
        if(!confirm('Are you sure?'))
            return false
}

$('a').click(confirmFn);
$('#target').delegate("a", "click", confirmFn);
$('button').click(function() {
    $.post('target.html', function(data) {
        $('#target').html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebinding your click handler upon loading the extra file?

```
var f;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').live("click", f=function() {
        if(!confirm("Are you sure?")) return false;
    });

    $('button').click(function() {
        $.post('target.html', function(data) {
            $('#target').html(data);
            $('a').unbind("click").live("click", f);
        });
    });
});
```

As well, I would check the console for errors.